# SQL Server solution to simple recursive function

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, recursive-query

I am looking for a SQL Server solution for a simple recursive formula. In the example, X is my column of numbers and Y is the column I am trying to create with a SQL Query.

I have a list of numbers, denoted X, and wish to produce a special kind of running sum that is not allowed to go less than 0, denoted Y.

Base Case

Y<sub>1</sub> = MAX(X<sub>1</sub>,0)

Recursive Rule

Y<sub>i</sub> = MAX(X<sub>i</sub>+Y<sub>i-1</sub>,0)

EXAMPLE:

```
id     X(Input)    Y(Output)
1      15          15
2      -87         0
3      26          26
4      -87         0
5      4           4
6      -19         0
7      34          34
8      -4          30
9      40          70
10     -14         56
```

Comment: Do you have a column that specifies the ordering of the rows?  SQL tables are inherently unordered, so if this is your entire table, you cannot do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a cursor and a table variable to catch the calculated values might be good for performance.

```
declare @T table
(
  id int,
  X int,
  Y int
);

declare @id int;
declare @X int;
declare @Y int;

set @Y = 0;

declare C cursor local static forward_only read_only for
  select T.id, T.X
  from T
  order by T.id;

open C;

fetch next from C into @id, @X;
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  set @Y = case when @X + @Y < 0 then 0 else @X + @Y end;
  insert into @T(id, X, Y) values (@id, @X, @Y);
  fetch next from C into @id, @X;
end

close C;
deallocate C;

select T.id, T.X, T.Y
from @T as T
order by T.id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fdd10/2)

Have a look at [Best approaches for running totals](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals) by [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an `id` column that specifies the ordering, I am pretty sure you have to do this with a recursive CTE.  The problem is that the "set negative numbers to zero" complicates the situation.

Let me assume that the `id` identifies the ordering.

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from table t
     ),
     cte as (
      select X,
             (case when X < 0 then 0 else X end) as Y
      from t
      where id = 1
      union all
      select tnext.X,
             (case when tnext.X + cte.Y < 0 then 0 else tnext.X + cte.Y end) as Y
      from cte join
           t tnext
           on t.id + 1 = tnext.id
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Comment: I successfully implemented this type of solution, but was wondering if it is flexible enough to handle the extension of the problem wherein I add a varchar column "product" and need to keep this same special running positive sum unique to each "product".  When ordered by id, the products would occur multiple times and appear randomly in the list.